# Copy the subdomain wordpress site into root directory of server with different domain

Tags: php, database, wordpress

- My project in subdomain(project1.com) i copied all folder and paste in root directory of server(project2.com) with different domain
- But problem is when i change the text in my (project2.com)template changes show perfectly
- When i logout from my project2.com  it shows the old text of project1.com
- I open the site in my mobile the text updated but in laptop it shows the project1.com text

i also use plugin for cache save the permlinks but it cannot work

Comment: do you changed database from copied wp-config.php file?

Comment: and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes i change in wp-config

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan i want to show my updated content but it shows the old content

Comment: do you have any errors/warnings in your new website?

Comment: errors not  show

Comment: updated content show in my mobile but in private window it show the old content subdomain content

Comment: so, you enabled debug mode and didn't get any error logs?

Comment: maybe, you have some cache plugin in your website

Comment: i deactivate all the plugins

Comment: some plugins may served their info in db. try to activate cache plugin, delete all cache files, then deactivate them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162685/discussion-between-unknow-and-samvel-aleqsanyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `W3 Total Cache` plugin. You disabled it, but it served cache files. You should to activate plugin, delete `cache` files, then can deactivate it.

When you're in development, it's great to keep non-active all cache plugins to not have some issues with them.